# Insert dynamically growing inputs into sql server 2008 using single sql query

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have html inputs that are created dynamically using a javascript. I want to populate a table in sql server 2008 database using a single query. I do understand this is possible when you have have a fixed amount of inputs/columns as shown below

```
INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )
```

My column list is expected to grow dynamically.I am using a foreach statement to try accomplish this.Here is my code

```
 if($_POST['postclaim'])
      {
     foreach($_POST['amt'] as $value)
         {
     $insert=mssql_query("INSERT INTO reserved (txn_id, proc_name,amount) VALUES ('1', '".$_POST['pdgen']."','".$value."' )");

      }

              }
```

'amt' and 'pdgen' are generated dynamically using a javascript. How do i insert the generated input values into the database?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @major....i want to know how i can insert the generated input values into the database from a single query

Answer (score 0):

You could construct the string in the loop and execute it at the end.

```
if($_POST['postclaim'])
{
    $InsertSQL = 'INSERT INTO reserved (txn_id, proc_name,amount) VALUES ';
    foreach($_POST['amt'] as $value)
    {
        $InsertSQL .= '(\'1\', \'' .  mssql_escape($_POST['pdgen']) . '\', \'' . mssql_escape($value) . '\'),');

    }
    $insert = mssql_query(substr($InsertSQL,0,strlen($InsertSQL)-1) . ';'); // The substr call here is to strip the trailing comma.
}

function mssql_escape($str)
{
    return str_replace("'", "''", $str);
}
```

Note the use of the custom-made `mssql_escape` to prevent SQL Injection attacks.